# Determine route that causes PayloadTooLargeError

Tags: node.js, express

We have a NodeJS app that uses Express.  We've seen a few PayloadTooLargeError message start to pop up, but the problem is we don't know whats causing it or how to recreate.  The error message also doesn't give us any indication of which route the error is occurring on.  Is there a way for the stack trace or error message to detail which route is causing the error?  We have quite a few routes with APIs from multiple services, so debugging them all is almost impossible.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a custom middleware that logs the request uri everytime a route is used? This way you can see which route is throwing errors, as it will have been logged as being 'used' right before the error shows up.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a custom middleware that logs the request uri before the route is called will allow you to see which uris are throwing errors.